# Responsive Datatable is not collapsing columns

Tags: datatable, datatables, responsive

[------->Picture dataTable responsive error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hckTn.png)

I am using datatTable of https://datatables.net/, with this link and script, I am using jquery and bootstrap4

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

It is working fine with computer screen but not with cellphone screen

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
*****
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div  id="textH4D"class="col-12">
          <h4 id="h4D">Devices</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="tablaDevices"class="col-12">
          <table id="table_id" class="display">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Column 1</th>
                      <th>Column 2</th>
                      <th>Column 3</th>
                      <th>Column 4</th>
                      <th>Column 5</th>


       </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                          <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                          <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
                          <td>Row 1 Data 4</td>
                          <td>Row 1 Data 5</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                          <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
                          <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
                          <td>Row 2 Data 4</td>
                          <td>Row 2 Data 5</td>
                      </tr>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I need help with that please

Comment: You need to add the JS file and the CSS file of the plugin:

    http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js
    http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/css/dataTables.responsive.css

Comment: Hi, thanks, I put it but it it still not working

Comment: Need to add `responsive: true`

Comment: @SachiTekina Where I need to put it? thank you for your answer

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/y315obr4/4/

Comment: @SachiTekina I still having this problem, I belive that maybe it is a bad configuration when I chose the css and js of the datatables